# How to detect if a program is executing under a thrown exception at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Can I detect at runtime inside method Helper() that the program execution is the result of a thrown exception?

Note, my goal is to avoid extending method Helper() to take an exception object as a input pararmeter.

```
public void MyFunc1()
{
  try
  {
    // some code here that eventaully throws an exception
  }
  catch( Exception ex )
  {
     Helper();
  }
}

public void MyFunc2()
{
   Helper();
}

private void Helper()
{
    // how can I check if program execution is the  
    // result of a thrown exception here.
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is one horrible hack involving [`Marshal.GetExceptionPointers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptionpointers.aspx) and [`Marshal.GetExceptionCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptioncode.aspx) that doesn't work on all platforms here it is:

```
public static Boolean IsInException()
{
   return Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() != IntPtr.Zero ||
          Marshal.GetExceptionCode() != 0;
}
```

From this page: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/07/25/detecting-if-finally-block-is-executing-for-an-manhandled-exception/

Comment: +1/2 for crazy solution and +1/2 for saying its a horrible hack

Comment: That only works for exceptions that started life as a Windows SEH exception.  Like NullReference or AccessViolation.

Comment: Thanks for the precision Hans. And thanks for the half points Simon. I think there is another "cleaner" hack involving the inspection of the stack frames, but I need to sleep, I'll try it out another time :-).

Comment: Thanks, this is the most correct answer given the question I asked.

Comment: Whoa, it's not.  Getting something out of GetExceptionCode() is the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant: Works fine for me with a plain `throw new Exception()`. Maybe this was changed?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think of any reason why you wouldn't do it like this:

```
private void Helper(bool exceptionWasCaught)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: In a perfect world I agree; however, my example simplifies my situation, I am trying to avoid changing the signature of the Helper method.

Comment: StackFrame class: nah.  No way to find out if an exception is being handled.  Global variable.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your answer, the idea for my question came to me when I was few layers deep in code and I did not want to change the method signatures.  In the end I decided to change the signatures given the answers I got.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of.  This is cumbersome, but it fully delineates you as the developer's intent:

```
private bool inException = false;

public void MyFunc1()
{
  try
  {
    inException = false;

    // some code here that eventaully throws an exception
  }
  catch( Exception ex )
  {
     inException = true;
     Helper();
  }
}

public void MyFunc2()
{
   inException = false;
   Helper();
}

private void Helper()
{
    // how can I check if program execution is the  
    // result of a thrown exception here.
    if (inException)
    {
        // do things.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is very bad design and I would never suggest code like that! Please people, dont use this code! Take "Hans Passant" Version or better pass the exception instead of a boolean.

Comment: In a perfect world I agree; however, my example simplifies my situation, I am trying to avoid changing the signature of the Helper method. – Zamboni 2 mins ago

Comment: @Scordo: I went out of my way to say it wasn't that great.  Many times people inherit code in which the methods can't have their signatures changed easily like that.  I agree with Hans' way, no doubt.  If you can show a solution with minimal invasiveness to method signatures that is cleaner, please contribute.

Comment: @Zamboni: I'm not changing method signatures.  In fact, I specifically am **not** as per your comment to Hans.

Comment: +1 simply because this is just about the only thing that answers the original question without modifying the signature of `Helper`. Yes, it's horrible, but only because the question is already horrible (for catching `Exception`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking this. If you have an exception, pass an exception. If you don't, don't.

Why don't you want to change the signature of the Helper() method?

```
public void MyFunc1()
{
  try
  {
    // some code here that eventually throws an exception
  }
  catch( Exception ex )
  {
     Helper(ex);
  }
}

private void Helper(Exception ex = null)
{
    // result of a thrown exception here.
    if (ex!=null)
    {
        // do things.
    } else {
        // do other things
    }
}
```