# C#: Throw an exception without overwriting the currently-active one

Tags: c#, exception, mono

Take the following minimal example:

```
try { foo }
finally { bar() }
```

`foo` may or may not throw, and `bar()` may or may not throw.
If both functions throw, then the exception thrown by `bar()` will overwrite the exception thrown by `foo`. However, I need to instead see the exception that was thrown by `foo`. The only code I can control is that inside `bar()`.
In C++, this can be achieved by checking `std::uncaught_exceptions` inside `bar()`.
What about C#?

There is [a check using Marshal.GetExceptionPointers()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551928/1347646), but as the answer states, this is a horrible hack, and in my case it does not suffice because my code needs to run on Mono, which does not implement that function.

Context:

In my real-life case, `foo` is a large block of code which is provided by the library user and may throw all sorts of exceptions, and `bar()` is a `Dispose` function which is provided by me and called automatically.

Comment: As you can control code in `bar` wrap it in try/catch block so outside you will see only exceptions thrown by `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to code this manually:

```
// Whether an exception has been thrown from the main block.
bool hasMainException = false;

try 
{ 
    foo();
}
catch
{
    // Record that exception has been thrown from main block, and rethrow.
    hasMainException = true;
    throw;
}
finally 
{
    // Execute secondary block within its own try-catch block.
    try
    {
        bar();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Only rethrow exception from secondary block if there isn't 
        // already an exception from the main block.
        if (!hasMainException)
            throw;
    }
}
```

Incidentally, I needed to achieve something very similar to your use-case involving `Dispose` methods that could throw, so I wrote some extension methods to achieve this, plus a variety of strategies to support all use-cases. See [`DisposableExtensions`](https://github.com/Douglas-Williams/DogmaMix.Core/blob/master/Core/Disposables/DisposableExtensions.cs) and [`DisposeExceptionStrategy`](https://github.com/Douglas-Williams/DogmaMix.Core/blob/master/Core/Disposables/DisposeExceptionStrategy.cs). The strategy you're interested in is [`Subjugate`](https://github.com/Douglas-Williams/DogmaMix.Core/blob/master/Core/Disposables/DisposeExceptionStrategy.cs#L49).

Comment: As I wrote, unfortunately the only code I can control is the one inside `bar()`, everything else is the library user's responsibility...

Comment: @mic_e: You're right; I missed that. I don't believe it can be done other than with the hack you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This will

- throw the exception from `foo`, even if an exception is thrown in `bar`.
- throw the exception from `bar` if there was no exception from `foo`.
- not throw anything if nothing throws an exception.
- preserve the original stacktrace from either exception.

  ```
      ExceptionDispatchInfo exceptionInfo = null;
      try
      {
          foo();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          exceptionInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
      }
      finally
      {
          try
          {
              bar();
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              exceptionInfo = exceptionInfo ?? ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
          }
      }
      exceptionInfo?.Throw();
  ```