# Alternative for Marshal.GetExceptionCode()?

Tags: c#, .net

Marshal.GetExceptionCode() has been obsoleted, and the message does not suggest a way forward.

at the moment I use this in the following opensource project:

https://github.com/dbones-labs/auditable/blob/master/src/Auditable/AuditableContext.cs#L143

the idea is, if the client code/app within a `using` block throws an exception it should not write a log.

However, the project code only has a `using` statement to figure out if it should react or not.

what is the alternative to this? (without changeing the API for the calling code)

example use of the API
https://dbones-labs.github.io/auditable/quick-examples/aspnet-example.html#3-add-some-auditable-logs

Comment: I think you can in any case catch an `SEHException` so I'm not sure what the point of this is. Furthermore it's not clear if this code actually uses unmanaged code so not sure what the point of checking it is anyway

Comment: @Charlieface I think he is using it like this: there is a `try { using { } catch {}` block. If the exception is thrown inside the `using {}` block , the unwinding of the stack causes the `Dispose()` to be called before the `catch {}` block is executed. In the `Dispose()` he checks the `Marshal.GetExceptionCode()?` to see if the `using` was exited in a "natural" way (return or passing the end of the using block) or violently through an exception

Comment: @dbones +1 I can't help you but it is a very nice trick. I didn't know. Not that I've ever had to handle a `Dispose()` in a different way if called during an exception. But still interesting.

Comment: @xanatos I think `SEHException` would still be throw no? And you can always flip round the `try` to the inside

Comment: @Charlieface But while you are inside the `Dispose()` you don't know if there is a SEHException "in the air"

Comment: @dbones Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551873/how-to-detect-if-a-program-is-executing-under-a-thrown-exception-at-runtime) it seems that the full check is two-pronged: `Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() != IntPtr.Zero || Marshal.GetExceptionCode() != 0;`. The first method won't be obsoleted... Try if it is enough

Comment: Kinda odd thing to do. Normally one catches any exception at source, log and rethrow. You don't try detecting an unwinding exception in `Dispose` that is just a code smell

Comment: @Charlieface it may be odd, but it looks natural to the person calling the library

Comment: Hmm, it might be that very code that made them decide to deprecate it :)  No, it completely does not do what it promises, only a (smallish) set of exceptions produce a non-zero result.  Worse, it does not help the client programmer diagnose a very serious bug in their code.  How many less "it showed up in your log so it is your bug" reports did it actually avoid?  Don't do this.

Comment: @Charlieface it's not a code smell at all. Python does that naturally with its context managers and being able to detect exceptions inside dispose makes it super easy to handle the started/completed case with a logger without tons of boilerplate code. Without this mechanics you need to "commit" every using with an explicit method call to propertly handle such a case.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick test it seems you can use [`Marshal.GetExceptionPointers()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getexceptionpointers?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_GetExceptionPointers):

```
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var ptr = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers();
        Console.WriteLine(ptr);
    }
}

try
{
    using (new MyDisposable())
    {
    }

    using (new MyDisposable())
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}

using (new MyDisposable())
{
}
```

It is non-zero if there is an `Exception` "in the air".

Note that `Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() was always present in .NET Framework but was reintroduced in .NET Core only >= 3.0. So for .NET Core 1.0-2.2 you'll need to use` Marshal.GetExceptionCode()`.

Comment: Nice one I will have a look at this (I did not want to introduce compiler directives)

Comment: i will accept this once i have this working